# How to call method after change the value from the watch in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="element-container"></div>
        <div id="error-handler" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            pgy: "",
            tapIsReady: false,
            auth: false,
        }
    },
    watch: {
        pgy: {
            handler: function (value) {
                this.fetchTap();
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchTap() {
            if (!this.auth) {
                return;
            }
            this.initTap();
        },

        initTap() {
            var tap = Tapjsli();
            var elements = tap.elements({});

            var taa = elements.create();

            // mount element
            taa.mount('#element-container');

            this.tapIsReady = true;
        },
    },
},
```

I need to call the `fetchTap` after change the value of `pgy`

`initTap` is called inside `fetchTap` which will init the `html` above

i got this error with that code:

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback

---

> error: Unhandled rejection Tapjsli/this.elements/this.elements.card.mount

I'm expecting to call the js library after changing the data value

Comment: You have an exception in your method. The watch is working correctly.  
Take a look at your console to see if you have an error log. Or add a `try / catch` around your `this.fetchTap()` to catch and log the error.

Comment: @Kapcash I added `try / catch` and got this error `TypeError: e is null` but when I use `flush: 'post'` in watcher it works!

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#callback-flush-timing

Comment: @Kapcash using `flush: 'post'` I got `this.tapIsReady = true;` always true the my spiner is not working :(

Comment: I guess this is a problem not related with the initial question. What spinner are you talking about? Isn't it what you want, to have your boolean to `true` at the end of the execution?

Comment: @Kapcash the spinner is not important to me, I want to know why with `flush: 'post'` is working ?!

Comment: That's because `flush: post` waits for Vue to update the DOM before calling the watch callback. By default, it's done before. So here, the callback was probably executed before the DOM elements required by TapJS were created.